# How can I tell if an instance implements an interface in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am overriding the addItem() function of an array collection and I would like to detect if the added item implements a particular interface.

Previously I used the, `is` operator to detect the class type, but now that I am using an interface for classes I would rather test to see if the object implements the interface.

I expect I could just try and cast the object as the interface and see if it's not `null`. Is this the best way to do it?

I could also just create a new `addFunction()` that only accepts objects of the interface type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can still use **is** to test for an interface.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" minWidth="1024" minHeight="768" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            public var test:TestInterface = new TestInterface() //implements ITestInterface


            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace(test is ITestInterface); //true
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, was rather lazy of me, but I wanted to know the right way to do it, rather than finding something that worked but may have been bad practice.

Comment: Good choice! Can you add "in AS3" to the end of the title?

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer of Joel: if you want more information about the interfaces a class implements (and its subclasses, parent classes, etc), the [AS3Commons](http://www.as3commons.org) library has a [ClassUtils](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/asdoc/org/as3commons/reflect/ClassUtils.html) class that has a number of convenience methods.